# how to cast string type data to my own class type

Tags: swift, casting, swift4

I have a Node class which is responsible to define name and coordinates of nodes. Instances of the class is already defined as nodeOne and nodeTwo. I’m trying to do string concatenation as shown in `var node: String = “node”+ userInput`and pass it to `test(source: Node)` which obviously accepts data as type Node.So, how to cast from string type to my class, Node? I tried to do `test(source: nodeOne as Node)`, but it throws an error can't cast on the runtime.

```
class Node {
    let name: String
    let coordinates: CGPoint

    init(name: String, coordinates: CGPoint) {
        self.name = name
        self.coordinates = coordinates
    }
}
```

class objects:

```
//defining nodes
let nodeOne = Node(name: "East Entrance", coordinates: CGPoint(x: 623.5, y: 166.0))
let nodeTwo = Node(name: "Main Entrance", coordinates: CGPoint(x: 621.0, y: 935.5))
```

```
var userInput: String = One

var node: String = “node”+ userInput 

test(source: nodeOne as Node)


func test(source: Node) {
If nodeOne.name == "nodeOne" {
    print(“node 1”)
   } else { 
    print(“node 2”)
 } 
}
```

Comment: What are the mistakes? @ElTomato

Comment: This is Swift. You can't create variable references using strings.

Comment: @rmaddy what if I make it as  an int.. node1 & node2.. and then var node: String = “node”+ String(userInput)? sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: That's the same thing. Instead of creating separate variables, put your Node instances in a dictionary. Then you can access them using a key you determine at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. This is the piece that I was missing.

Comment: @AliDeV Also, `Node` is a perfect candidate to be a `struct` instead of a `class`. For one, it lets you not need the initializer, because the exact same one would be synthesized for you implicitly by the compiler (called a "memberwise initializer")

Answer (score 0):

As per @rmaddy, the problem was solved by putting the Node instances in a dictionary of type `var myNodes: [Int: Node]`. and accessing them by their keys `myNodes.keys`